# InputDecoration prefixIcon not centers text

Tags: flutter

How can I center text in TextFormField?
It seems to me that additional padding is being applied that I have no control over.

My code example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLines: 1,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLength: 13,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      cursorWidth: 1.5,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        counterText: "",
        prefixIcon: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              '+254',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

You need to set `isDense` to `true` on the `InputDecoration`:

```dart
decoration: const InputDecoration(
    isDense: true, // <-- Add this.
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

However, the `prefixIcon` has a [default padding of 12 px](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefixIcon.html):

so you can also do:

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
```

---

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
        maxLines: 1,
        minLines: 1,
        maxLength: 13,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        cursorWidth: 1.5,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          counterText: "",
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '+254',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but in your screenshot the number 7 below prefix is not centered

Answer (score 0):

`prefixIcon` is generally for icons, you should use `prefix` instead.

```dart
prefix: Row( // change from 'prefixIcon' to 'prefix'
  // ...
)
```

Also you can remove the `Row` if it's only meant to wrap a child. Just use the `Text` widget directly as the `prefix`.

Result:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Notice how the prefix and the input text is actually aligned on the baseline. The difference comes from the font size. If you use the same `TextStyle`, it will look like this:

[image: Screenshot 2]